# Много однотипных Entity Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine2

Есть много одинаковых табличек, по типу table_2019, table_2018, поля в них идентичны. 
Можно ли как то настроить доктрину для работы с такими табличками, не плодя кучу Entity, а использовать какой-то базовый класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом, может кому пригодится, в Doctrine есть такое свойство для `PhphDoc` `@MappedSupperClass`, что позволяет создать базовую `Entity` от которой в дальнейшем можно будет наследоваться.

например:

```
/**
* @MappedSupperClass
**/
class BaseEntity {

    private $field1;

    private $field2;
}


/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="table_name")
*/
class Entity1 extends BaseEntity {

}
```

Это позволяет один раз описать базовую `Entity` а в дальнейшем просто примять её для однотипных таблиц